# How to use InlinePanel in ModelAdmin?

Tags: django, keyerror, wagtail

I'm setting up a model that needs to be created with a number of instances of a sub-model. I want to be able to edit and create this model in the admin interface so I'm adding it using [`ModelAdmin`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html). According to the [documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/contrib/modeladmin/create_edit_delete_views.html) I should be able to specify the fields/panels in accordance to normal `Page` types; however, when I add a [`InlinePanel`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/contrib/forms/index.html?highlight=InlineField) I get an `KeyError` on the related field name.

**models.py**

```
class Application(models.Model):
    # other fields....

    panels = [MultiFieldPanel([
        FieldPanel('applicant'),
        FieldPanel('position'),
        FieldPanel('cover_letter'),
        FieldPanel('qualifications'),
        InlinePanel('references'),
        FieldPanel('draft'),
    ])]


class Reference(models.Model):

    application = models.ForeignKey(
        Application,
        related_name='references',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
    )

    # other fields....
```

**wagtails_hooks.py**

```
class ApplicationAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Application
    menu_icon = 'mail'
    menu_order = 400
    list_display = # other fields....

modeladmin_register(ApplicationAdmin)
```

**Error**

> Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/involvement/application/create/
>
> Django Version: 1.10.5
>
> Exception Type: KeyError
>
> Exception Value: 'references'
>
> Exception Location: /[APPFOLDER]/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py
>   in **init**, line 627

I'm having trouble determining what I did wrong. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wagtail relies on the [django-modelcluster](https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster) library to allow the parent and child models to be handled in forms as a single unit. For this to work, the base Application model has to inherit from `modelcluster.models.ClusterableModel` (the Wagtail `Page` model does this as standard) and the child model has to be linked by a `ParentalKey` rather than a `ForeignKey`.

Child models in an `InlinePanel` are also typically subclasses of `Orderable`, so they can be sorted; off the top of my head I can't remember whether this is an absolute requirement, or just a recommendation.

```
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel

class Application(ClusterableModel):
    # ...

class Reference(Orderable):
    application = models.ParentalKey(
        Application,
        related_name='references',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
    )
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but isn't showing up in the Wagtail ModelAdmin UI.

Comment: @BrylieChristopherOxley you're right it's not showing!